# Rails move info from Headers to Body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-headers, response-headers

I tried to use Rails method `request.headers["Access-Token"]` to get Access-Token from Headers and move it to Body. But the problem is that headers' output looks like this:

https://pp.vk.me/c638121/v638121746/239b4/PF4NFzGBTio.jpg

Is there any way to access `Access-Token` from headers?

Comment: Is that the same response from `request.headers`?

Comment: yup, it's the output of `request.headers`. And if I access access-token like this `request.headers["Access-Token"]` it returns nil

Comment: Try `request.header['access-token']`

Comment: @user3693398 The commenter below suggested the same. Didn't work. Someone suggested this "    
Ok now the hard part is finding how deeply it is nested. At the very least it is @header[:access_token] however if that doesn't work you have to find out how many hashes/arrays it is inside and basically work your way to it. For instance it could be response[:something][:another_array][:another_hash][:header]‌​[:access_token]". But there's almost no way to know how deeply it's nested

Answer (score 0):

It seems just wrong the case of your key. This should work

```
request.headers["access-token"]
```

Comment: oh I wish it was that simple. Tried both - no luck

Comment: It's strange. I do the same way in an app I'm building and it works.